# How to get the MaxLength of a Column in a DataSet returned by ExecuteWithResults in C# SMO?

Tags: c#, sql, dataset, smo

I need to get the max length of any column returned in any SELECT executed in the ExecuteWithResults method.

Example:

The Table TbCli has the column NmCli (varchar NOT NULL)

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

...

Server server = new Server();
server.ConnectionContext.ServerInstance = "ServerInstance";
server.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = true;
server.ConnectionContext.DatabaseName = "DatabaseName";
server.ConnectionContext.Connect();

DataSet lQR = server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteWithResults("Select NmCli From TbCli");

var max = lQR.Tables[0].Columns[0].MaxLength;

Console.WriteLine("\n- End!"); Console.ReadKey();
```

In this example the max variable is assigned the value -1.
I need something that give me the number 50. (Because in this example the column is varchar(50))

Remember:

This is an Example. If someone send this query to my method:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Name, b.ID, b.Name From TableA as a inner join TableB as b on a.BID = b.ID
```

I need to be able to get the correct length of all the columns.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `exec sp_help 'tablename'`. It will return multiple result sets and the second one will give you the length of the columns.

**Edit:**
The following code block should give you what you want. I am not sure what is the complication based on your comment but I was able to create a dictionary with the column names, and the length of the columns.

```
            Server server = new Server();
            server.ConnectionContext.ConnectionString = @"ConnectionStringHere";
            server.ConnectionContext.Connect();

            var ColumnDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            using (SqlDataReader lQR = server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteReader("sp_help 'dbo.WhicheverTable'"))
            {
                lQR.NextResult();
                while (lQR.Read())
                {
                    ColumnDictionary.Add((String)lQR.GetValue(0),(Int32)lQR.GetValue(3));
                }

            }


            //Do anything with the dictionary here
            Console.WriteLine("\n- End!"); Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: This will not work for me because it may be a very complex select statement.
In my method i'll receive the select as a string. Do you see how your response my be very complex do apply in my case?

Comment: As i said, unfortunately i can't write my code based on the premise that I know the table name.
My method receive a string to execute in ExecuteWithResults. It can be anything. For example:
(1). A very complex SELECT statement. (more than 300 lines)
(2). A Stored Procedure.
(3). SELECT @@IDENTITY AS [@@IDENTITY]
(4). Etc...

Comment: The solution for that actually is pretty easy. All you need to do is to select into a table, could be dbo.Temp then call sp_help on that table. Afterwards, you can simply drop the table.

Comment: That's actually pretty helpful. Thanks!